# Remeshing deletes the insides of the mouth

Tags: remesh

In order to create a mouth that opens and closes i created an inside of a mouth like most characters.
the problem is every time i remesh the model it gets removed and the mouth becomes stitched again.
i don't know how to solve this issue i need to remesh all the time in order to polish the face but with this issue i can't remesh after creating the insides of the mouth
help please.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep a closed mouth from resealing when remeshing, but you might be able to find an easier way to unseal it, perhaps with Boolean. But anyway, why are you remeshing the head over and over?